# Google Play Store showing 0 Supported Android devices

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest, android-permissions

Details of my play store account as follows :

Features
6 features

```
android.hardware.CAMERA
android.hardware.FAKETOUCH
android.hardware.LOCATION
android.hardware.location.GPS
android.hardware.location.NETWORK
android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT
```

Required permissions
14 permissions

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.CAMERA
android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
com.enterprise.givo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES
```

Comment: post your manifest file. then try some other solution if not works.

Comment: Thanks for supporting the developers. you can upvote the answer also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

add required="false" on uses-feature tags